# Why fuse needs to be slightly more able to bear current than the appliance?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-engineering

if I have a bulb with rated current of $4 A$ then why I need to connect an $5A$ fuse?( which has slightly more ability to bear current.)

Comment: Because of the engineering principle of having a factor of safety.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_of_safety .

Comment: The startup current for many devices is often greater than the operating current; the design of the fuse must take this into account.  A fuse can be further designed to fail quickly, or to tolerate a brief over-current: quick or slow.

Comment: If the fuse is connected in series with the bulb and the purpose of the fuse is to save the bulb, then it should be rated lower than the bulb, as you suggest.
Is that the case?

Comment: It wouldn't be very useful to have the fuse blow every time you turn on the light.

Comment: Because theoretically 4 amp fuse is fine, but current varies easily and often.    Lets put it this way, would you prefer that someone cut a piece of parachute cloth to precisely be sufficiently small to let you fall without breaking your legs, or would you prefer a little leeway and have a slightly larger parachute?

Comment: I interpret by the question that "rated current" is the current where the bulb breaks, not the nominal current where it operates.

Comment: Would [electronics.se] be a better home for this question?

Answer (score 2):

The role of a fuse is not to protect the equipment from damage. It's to ensure that in the event of a fault, the wiring doesn't overheat and cause a fire.

The fuse needs to be rated slightly higher than the maximum operating current of the protected device, so that the fuse won't blow when the equipment is used.  It shouldn't be rated too much higher than the maximum operating current, because that would require wiring the equipment with thicker, costlier wire.

In case this is a homework question, I won't talk about the specific case of the lamp directly, but give a hint in the form of a question: What is the equivalent resistance of an incandescent lamp, and how does it depend on temperature?

Answer (score 0):

The actual amount of current that will cause a fuse with a given rating to open is a random variable that depends on random variables in the manufacturing process. Same goes for the light bulb: The actual amount of current that the light bulb will draw from a given supply voltage is variable.

In order to prevent blown fuses, you want the nominal rating of the fuse to be somewhat higher than the nominal rating of the light bulb, and in order to prevent house fires, you want the nominal capacity of the wires in the walls to be a bit higher than the rating of the fuse.